# NGINX Ingress Controller - 405 Not Allowed

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have developed a spring boot app (User Registration app) that has one rest API. The rest API inserts the data in a MySQL.
The application and database have been deployed in GCP Kubernetes and everything was working fine as I was using network load balancer.
Now I am trying to use NGINX Ingress Controller and Path-based Ingress routing. A network load balancer is pointing to NGINX Ingress Controller and Load Balancer IP is tagged to a wild card host name in Cloud DNS.

From PostMan application whenever I am trying to hit the "User Registration App" using the DNS url it's throwing an error:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>405 Not Allowed</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>405 Not Allowed</h1>
    </center>
    <hr>
    <center>openresty</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**I am trying to provide all the details I have right. Can provide more details if required. I am not able to understand why NGINX server is throwing "405 Not allowed error".**

### User Registration Spring Boot App

[Spring Boot App Controller - POST method receive the input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vf7MZ.png)

### NGINX Controller

Followed the steps mentioned here: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#detect-installed-version

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml

[Ingress Controller Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge6Dk.png)

### Kubernetes Services:

[Services Running in Kubernetes Cluster - Refer Yellow marked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67tJT.png)

### Kubernetes Pods:

[Pods running in Kubernetes Cluster - Refer Yellow marked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfB6Z.png)

**Ingress YML:**

```
`
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: fanout-ingress
  namespace: xyz-product
  labels:                     # Labels that will be applied to this resource
    app: prod-user-reg-app
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.apps.myproduct.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /user-reg/create/*
        backend:
          serviceName: prod-user-reg-create-app
          servicePort: 8081`
```

[Kubctl Describe Ingress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkFVH.png)

[GCP Cloud DNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVzhF.png)

**How do solve the issue? And where is the problem? In NGINX Controller service?**

Please help.

Comment: I am trying to access the application using url: http://test.apps.myproduct.com/user-reg/create/CreateUser/ from PostMan and passing the input values in JSON format

Answer (score 2):

The resolution is here. Changed the URL path and used a registered domain to access via the internet.

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/4772 and 
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/4776